# How to add an element to an array without a modification of the old array or creation a new one?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following construction: `for (String playerName: players)`.

I would like to make a loop over all `players` plus one more special player. But I do not want to modify the `players` array by adding a new element to it. So, what can I do?

Can I replace `players` in the `for (String playerName: players)` by something containing all elements of the `players` plus one more element?

Comment: You could create an implementation of `Iterable`, but the code is somewhat long and complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the contents of the loop in another method, and call it both inside and outside:

```
for (String playerName : players) {
    handlePlayer(playerName);
}
handlePlayer(anotherPlayerName);
```

Comment: +1: This is the easiest and IMHO best solution. No overhead for creating a new list or changing the old one and it improves the code by moving code into a seperate function.

Comment: @dbemerlin **Overhead** in creating a new list?? Probably going to be tiny (probably something in Apache Commons to do it with single-object overhead)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that @Bozhos answer is the best solution.

But if you absolutely want to use a single loop, you can use [`Iterables.concat()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)) from [Google Collectons](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) (together with [`Collections.singleton()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T))):

```
Iterable<String> allPlayersPlusOne=Iterables.concat(players,Collections.singleton(other));
for (String player : allPlayersPlusOne) {
  //do stuff
}
```